# create a flutter dropdown button like this

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

i want to create a flutter dropdown button like shown in the images below. this is an InkWell at the end of the row widget with text and assetImage. i want when a user clicks on the inkwell it display the options as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvKRv.png)

and after selecting from the options the inkwell will appear like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPePP.png)

the selected option should appear in red color in the menu list

Answer (score 0):

No need of dropdown use PopupMenuButton for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MenuAnchor for this.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MenuAnchor-class.html
Make a function that selects what item you clicked on and updates the ui accordingly

```
MenuAnchor(
      style: MenuStyle(
        side: MaterialStatePropertyAll(BorderSide(color: blue)),
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color?>(blue),
      ),
      builder: (context, controller, child) {
        return InkWell(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
            child: Transform.scale(
              scaleX: -1,
              child: Icon(Icons.),
            ),
          ),
          onTap: () {
            if (controller.isOpen) {
              controller.close();
            } else {
              controller.open();
            }
          },
        );
      },
      menuChildren: [MenuItemButton(
          child: Text(
            title,
          ),
        )],
    );
```